# Why didn't the Emperor and Vader learn from the encounter with Ahsoka?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious, star-wars-rebels

In [Rebels Season 4 Episode 13](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_World_Between_Worlds) Vader is about to kill Ahsoka

> when she disappears into the thin air, and goes to the "world between worlds". The Emperor finds out she is alive, and presumably later tells that to Vader.

But later both the Emperor and Vader are confident that Kenobi died on Death Star 1, although

> he also just vanished, like Ahsoka, leaving only his clothes behind.

Why didn't they learn from this experience that apparent death could be deceiving when powerful Force users are concerned ?

Comment: 1. Because it's a retcon, 2. I'm tempted to close this as per our Future Works Policy as this or a similar issue will likely be resolved in a later episode.

Comment: @Edlothiad Pardon me, but this is BS comment. Retcon is considered bad storytelling and this is certainly no future works. If disappearing happened once with the help of the Force, it could happen again

Comment: You're pardoned. A retcon is not _bad storytelling_ but simply "a piece of new information that imposes a different interpretation on previously described events, typically used to facilitate a dramatic plot shift or account for an inconsistency." This is then, certainly a retcon. As you've provided a different interpretation on previously described events. Secondly, given that we don't have an answer in the current canon, and the series isn't over, it likely does breach our Future Works Policy, as it will likely be covered in a later piece of canon.

Comment: It does seem like this is wide open to speculative answers and we're only likely to get a definitive answer from a future episode (of course, it's equally likely they'll never address it).

Comment: this is certainly future works / opinion based, because we don't yet know if there *is* anything to be learned. We don't know if Ashoka finds Ezra, reveals herself to Vader / Palpatine, gets involved at all in any way in the Rebellion, etc....

Comment: Also - it's not a retcon (Ashoka being saved) because Filoni is involved in all aspects of *Rebels* production. Ashoka's fate has been a matter of fan speculation, but Filoni has been cagey about it since her apparent death.

Comment: @Edlothiad Retcon is by definition bad storytelling, because it changes established facts retroactively. And this would be particularly bad retcon, because Vader would had opportunity to see Force user vanishing, and later finding out that Force user is still alive .

Comment: @NKCampbell Emperor definitely found out that Ashoka is still alive after vanishing in front of Vader in Season 2 . Connection with Kenobi is clear.

Comment: @rs.29 imagine it however you like.

Comment: @Edlothiad It is not imagination, it is established fact. Please watch episode before commenting.

Comment: @rs.29 - that is debatable. At best, the Emperor learns of her when he views Ezra and Ashoka through the world between worlds portal, but that doesn't prove that he knows that she makes it back to the 'real' world. The connection w/ Kenobi is not really viable, because their re-appearances are entirely different. Kenobi is clearly a ghost wheras Ashoka returns in full human form as far as we can tell. Also, at this point in the overall Star Wars story, Kenobi ghost hasn't happened yet, so we can't really say what they have learned or not from both situations

Comment: ...there is no evidence as of yet that Vader knows she is alive. Additionally - you are confusing retcon with an intended story point. Filoni planned this for Ashoka from the begining of that story - http://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2018/02/dave-filoni-discusses-reveals-of-world.html  - it would be a retcon to say that Kenobi and Yoda's disappearance is due to the being pulled into the world between worlds by another force user, but that isn't what is happening. What happened with Ashoka is (afawk) different, part of the original intention of the writer, and thus, not a retcon

Comment: @rs.29 I've seen the episode, but you calling retcon bad writing is you imagining it how you like.

Comment: @NKCampbell From Emperor's POV , both Kenobi and Ashoka disappeared after the fight vs Vader. Ashoka is clearly alive in some form, so why would Emperor believe that Kenobi is not, i.e. that he is destroyed . Ashoka could communicate with living, therefore it would be at least probable that Kenobi could too. Nore that Emperor does not know about Force ghosts.

Comment: You're missing the point here, and imagining more than the episode shows us, hence the future works close. We don't *know* that the Emperor knows Ashoka made it back to the real world. Also - don't discount Vader's own words in Empire Strikes Back "Obi Wan can no longer help him" - we've seen Force users 'feel' death - it stands to reason that Vader would feel Kenobi's true and real death, and that it would feel distinct from what happened with Ashoka as we now know it. Also, Vader saying that indicates how wrong he (and by extension, Palps) can be about the Force

Comment: @NKCampbell No, you are missing the point. Ashoka disappeared in Season 2. Suddenly, she is alive in "world between worlds" in Season 4. It doesn't matter if she could make back to real world, she exists - she is not destroyed. That means that Kenobi could be alive in some form after event on Death Star 1. Emperor and Vader could not be sure that he cannot help Luke . And in fact, he did help Luke after his apparent death .

Comment: @NKCampbell Emperor personally witnessed that you could be still alive after disappearing in real world - what is good for Ashoka could be good for Kenobi too.

Comment: whatever - we're talking past each other now, and you're wrong. Good day :)

Answer (score 3):

### Aside "vanishing", both situations had little in common

When Obi-Wan vanished, he had just been struck by a Vader's lightsaber, and left behind in his place were his robes and his own lightsaber. His body literally disappeared from within.

Contrast that to Ahsoka, who from Vader's perspective, had half an arm literally reach over from out of thin air to grab her, pulling her back into nothingness, along with all her possessions.

Vader knew his strike hit in the first scenario, and likewise knew it did not in the second. He knew someone intervened in the second, but had nothing to indicate likewise in the first. Weird for sure, and a little familiar, but too different to jump to the conclusion that he must have been rescued.

### But how could they be sure?

I mean, sure, maybe someone reached through the floor and grabbed Obi-Wan's leg and pulled him down out of his robes without Vader seeing. But what then? Do Vader and the Emperor have no way of being certain?

At least as far as what they know to be possible from Ahsoka's situation, they actually do have a way to check. The Emperor could just do what he did last time and call up the world between worlds and see if any Jedi happen to be hiding about.

This leads to two possibilities. Either 1) with the destruction of the temple, access to this space is now closed off, and the Emperor won't be able to see it, which confirms it wasn't involved. Or 2) He accesses it and sees if anyone inside, and knows again whether or not it was used. Even still, given the destruction of the temple, he'd have little reason to suspect it was even accessible or usable anyways.

### But what if...

Like you mention, maybe it was some different and presently unknown means of making someone vanish. How could they be sure?

After we've exhausted ruling out the above known means of pulling off this trick, there's really no point for Vader and the Emperor to waste their time speculate further. Maybe he's alive? But probably not. If it later turns out that he is, they'll just revise their understanding of the events and attempt to learn why and how he survived. But until then Occam's razor wins out, and the most likely situation is probably the one that occurred, and he's simply dead.

All of this even still presupposing that the Emperor was unaware of Force ghosts (which seems unlikely, given his and his master's research into surpassing death). If Palpatine did know, then he already knows what happened to Obi-Wan with a great deal of certainty.